# Use V8ScriptEngine in C# to re-run script multiple times with different parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, v8, clearscript

I have big JavaScript-library that I want to use within my C#-project and it works like a charm using the `Microsoft.ClearScript.V8`-nuget and the following code:

```cs
public int InvokeJavascript(int parameter)
{
    string libraryCode = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("library.js");
    string libraryInvokeCode = $"inoke({parameter})";
    string javascriptCode = $"{libraryCode};{libraryInvokeCode}";
    using (var engine = new V8ScriptEngine())
    {
        var result = engine.Evaluate(javascriptCode);
        return int.Parse(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the performance is really poor. I would love to **compile the code for the JavaScript Library only once and the invoke on the compiled script to avoid compiling it with every invoke**.

Do you have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: translate library.js to C# code ? ... :D

Comment: Almost impossible, the minified javascript code has several hundreds of kilobytes in size.

Comment: [using (var engine = new V8ScriptEngine())
{
 var input = new Input();
 engine.AddHostObject("input", input);
 using (var script = engine.Compile("function invoke(i) {return i;}; invoke(input.i)"))
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
   input.i = i;
   var result = engine.Evaluate(script);
   Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
 }
}

public class Input
{
 public int i { get; set;}
}](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bXOP6I)

Comment: of course you need to keep V8ScriptEngine and V8Script not disposed if you wana reuse it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-reading the library file, re-instantiating the script engine, and re-executing the library code for each call. Caching the engine lets you make multiple calls without all that overhead:

```
public sealed class JavaScriptInvoker : IDisposable {
    private V8ScriptEngine _engine = new V8ScriptEngine();
    private string _functionName;
    public JavaScriptInvoker(string libraryCode, string functionName) {
        _engine.Execute(libraryCode);
        _functionName = functionName;
    }
    public object Invoke(params object[] args) => _engine.Invoke(_functionName, args);
    public void Dispose() => _engine.Dispose();
}
```

Usage example:

```
const string libraryCode = "function invoke(a, b, c) { return a + b + c; }";
using (var invoker = new JavaScriptInvoker(libraryCode, "invoke")) {
    Console.WriteLine(invoker.Invoke(123, 456, 789));
    Console.WriteLine(invoker.Invoke("foo ", "bar ", "baz"));
}
```